# What will happen to default unity launcher when cairo dock is installed?

Tags: 11.04, unity

My question is will the default unity launcher be permanently be hidden when cairo dock is installed or not? If it will not be hidden how cam the two be managed together?

Comment: 1.nothing will happen. 2. yes they can be put toghether,  but i don't see why, if you have the launcher already would you wan't a second dock.

Comment: cairo dock is more appealing at least visually and has nice features which beats the unity launcher

Comment: true that, but if you're using unity3d or 2d you would have the launcher and cairo-dock, you can't have only the dock, even if you set the launcher to completely be hidden no matter what, it's part of the unity ui.

Comment: ok thanks any info how to customise the default appearance of 11.04 To make it more cool?

Comment: add more themes, and icon themes,wallappers add unity lenses,change the comiz effects to your likeing, other than that you can't any anymore, it's not as customizable as the classic desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run both at the same time there will be no connection between those two docks. Cairo has to be configured separately as always.

Comment: yep but while using unity , you can't just remove the launcher to replace it with a dock, more or less that's waht he wants.

Comment: He must use Classic Gnome for it

Comment: You can set the unity launcher to autohide in ccsm, so it wont bother you much.